# (PHP) I can't get a form action PHP code to work

Tags: php, html, forms

I am not sure what i am doing wrong, but i cannot get a PHP form action page to work, when i attempt to run it, it takes me to a blank page that does nothing. I am trying to create a simple code that redirects the user to a page depending on the input on the form. Here is what my form code looks like:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<font face="Stymie">ENTER SECRET CODE: <input type="text" name="secretcode"></font>
</form>
```

and here is what the index.php currently looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    if ($_POST['secretcode'] === "banana") {
        header("Location: banana.php");
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is one out of many codes i attempted to use, yet no matter what i put, it always takes me to a blank page. I also tried using GET instead of POST, but that just leaves me on the page without the code running.
Can someone tell me what i am suppose to do to get the code working? Help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I found a Javascript equivalent to this script which is a lot more efficient and simpler, thus i no longer need an answer.

```
<form onSubmit="return checkAnswer();">

<script>
function checkAnswer(){
var response = document.getElementById('secretcode').value;
if (response == "banana")
location = 'banana.html';
else
location = 'wrong.html';
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You lack a submit button

Answer (score 3):

Add a submit button:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <font face="Stymie">ENTER SECRET CODE: <input type="text" name="secretcode"></font>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"/>
</form>
```

And for the `php` code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       if($_POST['secretcode'] === "banana"){
          header("Location: banana.php");
       }
    }
?>
```

I added the `isset()` to prevent possible `Undefined index:` errors when you expand the `php` codes

**UPDATE**

I just tried OP's codes, it is submitting even without a submit button *(didn't know that, or maybe I just forgot)*.

It seems working for me, I am being redirected to `banana.php` when I typed `banana` in the `input`, the only problem I saw is the `Undefined index` error *(which the `isset()` will solve it)*

Comment: I tried that just now for both codes and it still doesn't work, i am still given a blank page, even when pressing the submit button.

Comment: Does `banana.php` have any content?

Comment: Yes, it's an edit of the page the form is in, with a different background color, different header text, etc.

Comment: It is working for me, I typed "banana", and I am being redirected to `banana.php`

Comment: Well I'd like to know some sort of diagnosis as to why it isn't working for me, I've even tried other browsers and even creating brand-new pages, yet the codes still don't work for me, and I'd like to see it fully working before i publish the site.

Comment: Create a fresh `index.php` then add my answer as the only content. Try redirecting to a non-existing page, you should receive an `Object not found` error

Comment: I'm still getting nothing, even when i redirect to a non-existent page, i get no errors in the console, only a "character encoding not declared" error which i think is normal.

Comment: It's ok, i no longer need an answer, for i have discovered a javascript alternative earlier today to doing this script which is more compact and efficient.